# PostgreSQL cascade updating many_to_many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, relationships

I have 3 tables to form `my many_to_many` relationship they are `services`, `appointments`, `appointment_service`. Now I'm trying to figure out how to update the `appointments` and `appointment_service` tables when an appointment is updated, more particularly when the appointment's services are updated (as in services can be added or deleted from an appointment).

The table structures are as follows:

```
appointments:
  - id
  - title

services:
  - id
  - name

appointment_service:
 - id
 - appointment_id
 - service_id
```

My first implementation would be to delete all the rows from `appointment_service` that match the appointment `id` I have to update:

```
DELETE FROM appointment_service WHERE appointment_id = ?;
```

And then add all of the "updated" services back to the pivot table:

```
WITH appointment as (UPDATE appointments SET column = ? WHERE id = ? RETURNING *) 
INSERT INTO appointment_service(id, appointment_id, service_id) 
VALUES (?, (select appointment.id from appointment), ?)
```

This works; however, I would like to turn these 2 queries into 1 so if deleting the`appointment_service` succeeds but updating the `appointments` query fails I don't have to go back and manually re-insert the rows for `appointment_service`. Also is there a better approach to the problem? Does PostgreSQL have some helper methods to achieve this in a cleaner way?

Comment: an m2m table is not called a pivot table.

Comment: @EvanCarroll What do you call it? I come from the Laravel world and they call it pivot_tables

Comment: *A linking table*, or even an *m2m table* (perfectly fine). For a pivot table to be true, it means there must be an unpivoted form of the data. That means there must a form of the data that has `(attribute,k,v)`. It refers to something different.

Comment: All of that said, I don't understand your problem here. My advice is to either show us the sample tables, sample data, and the code to create them, and the desired output.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I've added the table structures

Comment: I still have to read.. I don't want to read. I've tried that.  Show us the DDL. `CREATE TABLE...` `INSERT `... then show us the desired result and we'll tell you how to do it. I promise, it's *less* work on both of us.

Comment: @EvanCarroll it is not its most common name but actually it is (sometimes) called "pivot table". See wikipedia about [Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity): *"Associative tables are colloquially known under many names, including association table, bridge table, cross-reference table, crosswalk, intermediary table, intersection table, join table, junction table, link table, linking table, many-to-many resolver, map table, mapping table, pairing table, pivot table (as used in Laravel - not to be confused with pivot table (spreadsheets)), or transition table."*

Answer (score 0):

How about using array to downgrade the n-to-n link table to a 1-to-n table.

```
| appid int | srvids int[] |
| 1         | [5,4,6]     |
| 2         | [7,6]       |
```

this way when you update the relationship directly, no insert after delete.
just

```
-- Delete / Append
UPDATE app_srv_rel 
  SET srvid = array_remove(srvids, old_srvid ) / (srvids || new_srvid)
  WHERE appid = x

-- Update
UPDATE app_srv_rel 
  SET srvid = array_replace(srvids, old_id, new_id )
  WHERE appid = x

-- list all srvid 10 appids
SELECT * FROM app_srv_rel
  WHERE ARRAY[srvid] <@ srvids
```

More operations can be found in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) .

This really is not a `pivot table` which most of the time refers to [cross-tab aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).

Comment: I thought about just making it an array before my only concern is that appointments can grow to hundreds if not thousands of services. Having an array with 1000 elements just doesn't feel right. Would you still recommend going the array route?

Comment: I am not sure, I never used array extensively. the variables here are many, if you have ~1k services to each appointment, your n-to-n table will quickly get bloated, plus neither key is unique. I doubt if indexes scan will be faster than sequential scan, compared to that, at least 1-to-n gives you a unique key and thousand times less entries. But I really have no idea about array efficiency.